# JavaScript get multiple innertext

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to scrape a website. There are a few texts that I need to get which are in the same type of HTML tag/

```
<div class="card__title">
   <div class="visually-hidden">Title</div>
text i want</div>
```

how I can extract all of the innertext values?

I can get only the first one with this

```
await page.$eval('div[class="card__title"]', e => e.innerText)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it this way.

```
var cardTitleCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('card__title');

for(var i = 0; i < cardTitleCollection.length; i++) {
  var item = cardTitleCollection[i];

  console.log(item.innerText)
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/RwGbJxE

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the nodes inside your target element using `querySelection` which will return a collection, convert to array, and filter the text nodes.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.card__title').childNodes;


var textNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( el, 0 ).filter(item => item.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)

console.log(textNodes[1].nodeValue)
```

```html
<div class="card__title">
   <div class="visually-hidden">Title</div>
text i want</div>
```